# How can I append a option to several selects?

Tags: jquery

Guys I'm trying to append a option node to several selects but the option is just appended to the last select. How can I deal with it?

"option" is my option node. ".extraItemList" is a class that all my selects have.

```
$('.extraItemList').not('select.current').append(option);
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/sf5apgqa/1/

Comment: BTW, you can do it with one selector: `$('.extraItemList:not(.current)')`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

I just wrapped my option with "$()" and now it's working.

Thanks @Barmar!